# Not able to automate desktop application using sikuli

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, sikuli

I am using Sikuli to try to automate a desktop application for user authentication. Sikuli has been able to automate almost everything except for a part in application where a popup appears and disables the whole screen except for the popup itself. Sikuli shows the the error `Find failed` when I am trying to control an element on the screen.

I have tried running Sikuli and eclipse as an admin but that didn't work out.

The code I am using:

```
Screen screen = new Screen(); 
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("xyz.PNG"); 
screen.click(pattern);
```

Below is the image:[image]

Comment: Does your error appear while you having the popup displayed on the screen? Are you trying to interact with that popup and this is when the error appears?

Comment: the eclipse error occur when the pop up is on the screen .. it is when i am trying to interact when the error has occurred.

Comment: Please provide more info. Post you code and show exactly where it fails, include the actual error message. Perhaps add a screenshot as well.

Comment: code that i have used is a simple screen pattern code:                    Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("xyz.PNG");
screen.click(pattern);

Answer (score 0):

Could be a couple of things: 
 
 - You need to give it a few seconds for the pop-up to show itself, you could use a `wait()` for that. 
 - Try to make your script focus on the pop-up screen itself, for that you could use `App.focusedWindow()`.

For example:

```
popupWindow = App.focusedWindow()
if (popupWindow.exists(<fillInImageName>)):
       # Do something...
```

Comment: have tried this one. It is not able to switch/focus on to the pop up that appears on the screen..

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities you are having a problem with you script.

1. You are not waiting enough time to let the screen stabilize. To test that option, just add some wait time explicitly to ensure that your dialog appear on the screen when you're trying to interact with it.
2. You might have set your pattern incorrectly. What is the exact element of the dialog that you are trying to interact with? Is that the Password field? Please note that it might be tricky to match directly as there is a cursor (probably blinking). If that's the case, try typing straight to it instead of matching the field. Again, allow appropriate wait time.

Comment: i am using the code
Keyboard keyboard = new DesktopKeyboard();
keyboard.type("abc");
for which i am using import
import org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopKeyboard;

but it shows compilition error saying import .org.sikuli cant be resolved

Comment: Don't use this class for typing. Typing is available through `Screen` class as it extends the `Region` class that enables typing directly. So `s.type("abc")` will work (`c` here is an instance of `Screen`).